# Three different, and somewhat difficult, sequence puzzles

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

Here are three different letter/number sequences. Try to solve as many as possible. The spoilers give hints to each sequence in the form of how many elements are in the corresponding sequence.

Sequence 1 (Missing Elements: 2) [Solved by [xnor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10936/9631)]

```
Y, Y, ?, L, Y, E, ?, T, R...
```

> There are 12 elements in this sequence.

Sequence 2 (Missing Elements: 2) [Solved by [Tryth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10941/9631)]

```
a, H, R, 0, c, ?, o, ?, L, 3, B...
```

> There are 44 elements in this sequence.

Sequence 3 (Missing Elements: 3) [Solved by [finsternis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/11152/9631)]

```
?, P, C, P, C, ?, B, R, B, R, ?, R, S, R, S, R...
```

> There are 29 elements in this sequence.

The first one is quite simple but the other two are fairly challenging. Good luck!

Comment: 2 and 3 are really tough one, spend around 1 hour to analyse country group, country/capital group for puzzle 3, no result so far. Taking time out.

Comment: Why didn't you ask this as three separate questions?

Comment: @enoughreptocomment now that I see how difficult the last one is, I would consider it but that is something I never thought of doing at first.

Comment: Sequence 3 is currently the [sixth most famous 29-element sequence on the internet](https://www.google.co.uk/search?complete=0&hl=en-GB&source=hp&q=sequence+of+29+elements&btnG=Google+Search&gbv=2) - well done!

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks! I'm honesty surprised that no one has guessed it by now.

Comment: waiting for third sequence answer :)

Comment: Maybe a hint for the third one? I've tried alphabetical, mathematical, geographical, and chemical-element approaches to no avail.

Comment: Well I will say that I did not make the third sequence myself. I just converted another into one letter elements. However, our friends at Writers.SE might know who made the original sequence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sequence 3:

> Order of speakers in Shakespeare's Romeo and Juliet Act I, Scene ii:
>  **C**apulet, **P**aris, **C**apulet, ...
>  The full sequence is C, P, C, P, C, S, B, R, B, R, B, R, S, R, S, R, S, R, S, R, S, R, S, R, S, B, R, B, R
>  and the missing elements are C, S, and B.
>  (S = Peter the servant)

Comment: WOW! How on earth did you manage to solve this? Really impressive.

Comment: Bravo! Out of curiosity, did you use my hint?

Comment: Yes, the hint really helped!

Answer (score 26):

Sequence 2:

> This represents the base64 encoded form of the string `http://puzzling.stackexchange.com`. This corresponds to `aHR0cDovL3B1enpsaW5nLnN0YWNrZXhjaGFuZ2UuY29t`. Therefore the missing elements are **D** and **v**.

Comment: I did not expect anyone to get that so fast. Good job!

Comment: Can you post your method for how you solved this?  Did something point you to base64 encodings?

Comment: @user1717828 When I see mixed uppercase, lowercase and numbers base64 is usually my first guess.

Answer (score 22):

Sequence 1:

> Last letters of months:
>  Januar**y**, Februar**y**, Marc**h**, Apri**l**, Ma**y**, Jun**e**, Jul**y**, Augus**t**, Septembe**r**, Octobe**r**, Novembe**r**, Decembe**r**
> which gives the sequence `Y, Y, H, L, Y, E, Y, T, R, R, R, R`.
> The missing elements are `H` and `Y`.

Comment: I was just about to post this, lol.